# how to parse volume in dockerfile for an application to be pushed on docker hub

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /Users/vaibmish/Documents/new/graph-report

RUN pip install graphreport==1.2.1

CMD [ cd  /Users/vaibmish/Documents/new/graph-report/graphreport_metrics ]
CMD [ graphreport ]
```

**THIS IS PART OF DCOKERFIILE**

*i wish to remove cd volumes from tha file and have a command like -v there so that whoever runs that can give his or her own volume path in same*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
CMD [ cd  /Users/vaibmish/Documents/new/graph-report/graphreport_metrics ]
```

is wrong. You achieve the same with WORKDIR:

```
WORKDIR  /Users/vaibmish/Documents/new/graph-report/graphreport_metrics
```

WORKDIR creates the path if it doesn't exist and then changes the current directory to that path (same as `mkdir -p /path/new && cd /path/new`)

You can also declare the path as a volume and instruct who runs the container to provide their own path (docker run -v host_path:container_path ...)

```
VOLUME /Users/vaibmish/Documents/new/graph-report
```

A final note: It looks like these paths are from the host. Remember that the paths in the Dockerfile are not host paths. They are paths inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

Typical practice here is to pick some fixed path inside the Docker container.  It should be a different path from where your application is installed; it does not need to match any particular host path at all.

```sh
FROM python:3
RUN pip3 install graphreport==1.2.1

WORKDIR /data
CMD ["graphreport"]
```

```sh
docker build -t me/graphreport:1.2.1 .
docker run --rm \
  -v /Users/vaibmish/Documents/new/graph-report:/data \
  me/graphreport:1.2.1
```

(Remember that only the last `CMD` has an effect, and if it's not a well-formed JSON array, Docker will interpret it as a shell command.  What you show in the question would run the **test**(1) command and not the program you're installing.)

---

If you're trying to install a single package from PyPI and just run it on local files, a Python virtual environment will be much easier to set up than anything based on Docker, and will essentially work as you expect:

```sh
python3 -m venv graphreport
. graphreport/bin/activate
pip3 install graphreport==1.2.1

cd /Users/vaibmish/Documents/new/graph-report
graphreport

deactivate  # switch back to system Python/pip
```

All of the installed Python code is inside the `graphreport` virtual environment directory, and if you don't need this application again, you can just delete the directory tree.